# My bundle file does not open

Tags: macos, operating-system, bundle

I have a .bundle file. I've tried running it with the sudo command, and it just gives me errors. I've tried opening it because I was told there are files in it.

Any suggestions or apps I can use to open this .bundle??

Answer (score 0):

You can use Finder to browse through files in a bundle. Just use `Show Package Contents` context menu.

[image: Finder]

Comment: @BenjaminErichsen then this is not an OS X bundle (which is physically a regular directory).