# Open a bundle file with Mac

Tags: ios, macos, apple-m1

I am trying to open an bundle file on my Mac Big Sur version 11.3.1 with Apple M1. I thought .bundle files are Mac specific files so there should be also something built in which opens this files. This is not the case. How can I open the file with Mac? Other ressources like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482621/my-bundle-file-does-not-open) didtn't were useful. [image]

Comment: If it is an OS X bundle you may try to go to directory using full path name : either in terminal with cd …./lib…bundle or with finder goti directory…

Comment: I am able to go to the location but I am not able to open the file. @PtitXav

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bundle is just a file directory with a defined structure that the Finder treats as a single file. Unless it is an App Bundle it is not executable.

But you can examine the contents of the bundle if you control-click the file and choose "Show Package Contents"

If you do not have a "Show Package Contents": Control-click on the file, hold down option, choose "Copy ... as Pathname".

[image]

Open the Terminal and type `cd "`,  paste the clipboard, followed by a closing `"` and hit enter. If your bundle was called `My.bundle` on the Desktop the Terminal would look like similar to this:

[image]

If you get an error, it is not actually a `Bundle`, but a plain file with the name `.bundle`.

If you don't get an error, type `open .` followed by return and it will open the Bundle contents in the Finder.

Comment: For some reasons control-click doesn't work for me to show up the package contents. I just see Open and Open With.

Comment: See edit to help trouble-shoot.

Comment: I got the following error `not a directory: /Users/maxhager/Desktop/libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.bundle` so it is a plain.

Comment: I need to open this file. Normally it should a file to work with and no useless plain file. Do you know any workaround to deal with this?

Comment: From where did you get it ? May be it is not a bundle but some other file type used to be able to download it (like tar.zip,…)

Comment: Its is in a Unity package and the file exists with the installment of the package. @PtitXav

Comment: Paste this command into the terminal: `file /Users/maxhager/Desktop/libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.bundle` followed by return. What does it say?

Answer (score 3):

There is a third option aside from the two that Jeshua outlines, which is that this is a bundle of a git repository, in which case you need to use git to open it.

I would probably do

```
git clone My.bundle PathToFolderYouWantCreated
```

after which you can cd into the folder created to hold the bundle.